# Skype for linux won't launch

Tags: linux, gentoo, skype, voip

I am trying to launch the newest skype versions (~)8.57.0.116-r1 (~)8.58.0.93 on my Gentoo and it won't launch, the only error being this line in `dmesg`

```
traps: skypeforlinux[17278] trap int3 ip:55e99ed962ff sp:7ffc54486f30 error:0 in skypeforlinux[55e99ce7f000+5422000]
```

I tried `chmod 4755 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/chrome-sandbox`, but there is no chrome-sandbox in the package's files whatsoever.

Comment: Do you install it with emerge from [official repositories](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/net-im/skypeforlinux)?

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: BluemanCZ, Yes, I install it from official repositories.

Comment: I found Gentoo ebuild is set to remove `chrome-sandbox` according to [this bug](https://bugs.gentoo.org/692692#c18). Maybe you could try to use it by extracting `skypeforlinux-<version>.rpm` archive and copying `chrome-sandbox` file to `/opt/skypeforlinux/`.

Comment: Another solution could be enabling `CONFIG_USER_NS=y` in your kernel configuration and kernel recompilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` and then try to restart it and see if it starts up.

I remember an issue on Arch where it required access to unprivileged user namespaces.